# Returning username in django 1.10 drf jwt response

Tags: django, python-2.7, jwt, django-1.10, django-rest-framework

I've been fiddling around with `JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER` trying to get a username returned in the output

So I tried this in my `myApp/views.py`:

```
def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    if user and request:
      return json.dumps({
        'token': token,
         'username':  str(request.user.username)
      })
    else:
      return { 'token': token }
```

and then I tried this in my `project/settings.py`:

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'myApp.views.jwt_response_payload_handler'
}
```

doing a curl request I get the error message:

`TypeError at /api-token-auth/
<User: nunya> is not JSON serializable`

I'm so close to figuring this out ... but I'm missing something.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to figure it out:

```
# myApp/views.py
def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
  return { 'token': token, 'username': unicode(request.data['username']) }
```